# How to print next paper when print job is completed

Tags: c#, .net

How to Print Next Paper when the previous print job is completed

I want to print a group of papers at once, and I do not want to send them to the printer all at once. Whenever the printer finishes the first command, I send it the Next Paper

I couldn't find any solution and ideas

Comment: Could you please explain what you have accomplished so far?